# How to make a something continue until its true in android

Tags: android, continue

Okay so in my program i have something that when the database KEY_TITLE is empty them it says a certain thing until the user goes till the main menu to do something. My question is how do i check to see if its not empty anymore and continue with the program?
Here is the part of code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    insert.setText("");
    text.setText(" Try it out! Go to the main menu and schedule a task!");

    respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    mDbHelper2.fetchAllReminder();
        if(TaskDbAdapter.KEY_BODY.isEmpty() ){
            text.setText("Go and Schedule a task to continue =)!");
        }else{
            String task = new String(TaskDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
            insert.setText("");
            text.setText("text");
        }
```

Here is my code... Im having trouble to check the KEY_TITLE and do the else once the user schedules a task and returns to the activity and clicks the button again.

Comment: Try to post some code, it's too hard to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: You should add code, your question is totally fuzzy. If you can know something is empty (to display certain things...) then you can also know when it's not empty.... Impossible to understand anything.

Comment: @Egor @Snicolas Okay ive updated some source code. Hope you guys can help and see what im trying to do.

Comment: Not sure what you've done exactly,but it looks like but the quoted and unquoted code you've provided both have their own little problems which make them very hard to parse.  Have you centred the code using spaces before posting?  And if so, why?

Comment: okay so ive edited the code it should be more readable now. If anyone can help i will definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If by "main menu" you mean something outside your app, then you can check the condition by overriding `onResume()` in your activity.

If it's inside your app, then write a notification method and call it when the code that does whatever the user is supposed to do actually runs.